# Checking if a table contains values in a list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a parameter list of strings and I want to write a query that returns a list of strings that contain values of the parameter list that are present in the table. I have the following query but I can't get the where clause:

```
List<string> TheListParameter = new List<string>{"string1", "string2", "string3"};

var TheOutput = (from t in MyDC.SomeTable        
                 where t.SomeColumn.Contains(TheListParameter) 
                 select t.SomeColumn).ToList();
```

How do I write the `where` clause for this search query?

Comment: I think I actually misread your question... Do you need `SomeColumn` to *equal* `string1` or to *contain* `string1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ Oneliner

```
List<string> TheListParameter = new List<string>{"string1", "string2", "string3"};

var foundElements = MyDC.SomeTable.Where(a=> TheListParameter.Contains(a.SomeColumn)).Select(a=> a.SomeColumn);
```

Why everyone throws on the `ToList()` is beside me. It all depends on if you need all the data realized or not.

Take this example.

```
using(dbCtx myDc = new dbCtx()){
    var unrealizedList = myDc.someEntity;
    var realizedList = myDc.someEntity.ToList();

    var a1 = unrealizedList.First() //Works 
    var b1 = realizedList.First() //Works 
}
var a2 = unrealizedList.First() //Fails as unrealizedList is empty (not loaded and context is gone)
var b2 = realizedList.First() //Works because the realizedList was loaded completely by the ToList()
```

Now if you have a global or local (not a using) Ctx then you might never need `ToList()` albeit using `using` is a nice and clean way of gaining control over your context which can be a problem when you have several contexts working on eachother.

A tiny pointer on `ToList()` mid query.

```
var a = myDc.someEntity.Where(a=> a.someDate.DayOfYear == 123); 
// Fails as DayOfYear cannot be translated to  SQL expression
```

Here you need to project the data before you filter it, and sadly all the data needs to be loaded to do so

```
var a = myDc.someEntity.ToList().Where(a=> a.someDate.DayOfYear == 123); 
// Works as the data no longer is filtered in SQL (the SQL is "Select * from someEntity")
```

So if you can, perform your filtering before the `ToList()` to limit the amount of data pulled from the DB.

Instead if `ToList()` you can use other lists aswell like `ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
  List<string> TheListParameter = new List<string>{"string1", "string2", "string3"};

  var TheOutput = (from t in MyDC.SomeTable
                   where TheListParameter.Any(e => e == t.SomeColumn)
                   select t.SomeColumn).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on `Contain`'s [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx) the parameter for `Contains` could be `string` not a list of string. So it should be like this:

```
List<string> TheListParameter = new List<string> {"string1", "string2", "string3"};

var TheOutput = (from t in MyDC.SomeTable
                 where TheListParameter.Contains(t.SomeColumn.ToString())
                 select t.SomeColumn).ToList();
```

Or if you want to return a boolean result if `MyDC.SomeTable.SomeColumn` contains one of the `TheListParameter`'s strings you can try something like this:

```
bool hasSameElements = MyDC.SomeTable.ToList()
                      .Select(c => c.SomeColumn)
                      .Intersect(TheListParameter).Any(); //True or False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<string> TheListParameter = new List<string>{"string1", "string2", "string3"};
var result = MyDC.SomeTable.ToList().Select(l => l.SomeColumn)
                           .Where(l =>TheListParameter.Contains(l.SomeColumn)).ToList();
```