# In linq to sql how to apply && condition with a variable size or array

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the below table `AttachmentToTagMappings`

[image]

And I have an array which contains some tag id as shown below and the size can change in every execution.

`int[] tagIds= new int[] {1,2,9}; //again the number of elements can change in every execution for example in next execution it may be {1,2,7,12} because the this time the user is looking for the file(s) which are/is mapped to 1,2,7 and 12`

Now I want to write a linq by which I can get fileId(s) which are mapped to the above array `tagIds` elements. i.e. in above table `FileId` 201 is mapped to 1,2 and 9 so retrieve it but not 202 cause its only mapped to 1 and 2.

Comment: are you looking for &&, that seems to be where TagId == position 0,1,2,3,4 and so on, meaning every entry in the tagIds array would be the same for the condition to match. Or should it be or?

Comment: I think you want `||` instead of `&&` - `AND` would only be true if the ID matched ALL IDs in the list, which is not possible with the example list you show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a table contains values in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710141/checking-if-a-table-contains-values-in-a-list)

Comment: @Dhunt its `&&`. For example in the table I have a file call read.me and it is mapped to 3 different tags 1, 2, 3. Now I want all such files which has all three tags 1, 2, 3. So its `&&`

Comment: In that case none would ever match, based on the tagIds example you have. TagId cannot = 1,2,3 & 4. I think contains is right as other answers suggest but there might be some other changes needed too.

Comment: What is the type of `TagId`? Is it a collection?

Comment: Can you show the relevant entity classes?

Comment: @Riki but right now you're comparing _one value_, not a list of values.  If `TagId` is `1` it cannot be equal to both `1` AND `2`.

Comment: @Dhunt I have updated my question, I hope this will help to understand the problem.

Comment: @DStanley I have updated my question, I hope this will help to understand the problem.

Comment: @Riki given {1, 2, 9}, you want to find 201 and given {1, 2, 7, 12} you want to find 202 is it? and any other combination, you will find nothing?

Comment: @Ian no, that is all.

Comment: if field 202 has {1,2,9,12} instead of {1,2,7,12},we should take 202? @Riki

Comment: @Riki "no, that is all" sorry, I don't get it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Riki If you have { 1, 2, 7, 9, 12 } what will you return?

Comment: @Ian the table is showing 1 to many relationship. A fileId can be mapped to multiple tagIds. So now I want to write a linq by which I can get fileId(s) which are associated to a given set of tagIds. In the example table I was trying to tell that if the user has searched for fileId(s) which are mapped to TagId 1,2,9 the user will see 201 fileId cause in the example table this is the only file which is mapped to those 3 tags. Sorry if I'm not able to make my point :(

Comment: Can you show the class which has the TagId on it, I think it is File.

Comment: @Riki Ok, I get your point on that... my question is if the user has tagIds of {1, 2 } for example, will he see fileId 201 and 202 or will he see nothing (because of incompleteness)? And secondly, if the user has {1, 2, 7, 9, 12} will he see fileId 201 and 202 or will he see nothing because of over-completeness?

Comment: @Ian If the the user has tagId {1,2} the user will see 201 and 202 cause both fileIds are mapped to {1,2}. And the user has tagId {1, 2, 7, 9, 12} then the user will not see anything cause non of the files are associated to all these provided tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

To solve this problem, I would make use a couple of `LINQ`s like `GroupBy`, `let` and `Except`.

Here is my solution:

```
var grp = context.AttachmentToTagMappings.GroupBy(x => x.TagId);
int[] tagIds = new int[] {1,2,9};
var fileIds = from g in grp
              let grpFileIds = g.Select(y => y.FileId)
              let remFileIds = tagIds.Except(grpFileIds)
              where remFileIds.ToList().Count == 0
              select g.Key;
```

Or,

```
int[] tagIds = new int[] {1,2,9};
var fileIds = from attm in context.AttachmentToTagMappings
              group attm by new {attm.TagId} into g
              let grpFileIds = g.Select(y => y.FileId)
              let remFileIds = tagIds.Except(grpFileIds)
              where remFileIds.ToList().Count == 0
              select g.Key;
```

Assumption: `attm.TagId` type is the same as `tagId`, that is, an `int`
**Input-Output Results**

```
{1, 2} -> 201, 202
{1, 2, 9} -> 201
{1, 2, 7} -> 202
{1, 2, 7, 9} -> nothing
```

**Explanation**

1. Using `GroupBy` you could first group your `AttachmentToTagMappings` based on its `TagId` thus creating two `groups`, one identified by `201` and having three `attm` members whose tag ids are `1, 2, and 9` respectively. Another `group` has key of `202` with four `attm` members whose tag ids are `1, 2, 7, and 12` respectively.
2. Using `let` we want to create an `IEnumerable<int>` `grpFileIds` for each group. `grpFileIds` contains only the group's `file ids`
3. Next, Using `Except` we want to omit all the `tagId` in `tagIds` which is contained in `grpFileIds`, resulting in the remaining `remFileIds`
4. If the `remFileIds.Count` is zero, it means all items in `tagIds` has a pair in the `grpFields`. Otherwise, if the `remFileIds.Count` is greater than zero, meaning at least there is one `tagId` which the group does not have
5. Select all keys in the group (that is `201`, `202`, etc) whose `remFileIds.Count` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` should be translated to an `IN` clause in SQL which seems to be what you want:

```
where tagIds.Contains(attm.TagId)
```

Comment: `Contains` will retrieve file names which has tags either 1 or 2 or 3 or 4... but I need all file names which are associated to all provided tags

Comment: Please provide more details about your data model and exactly what you're looking for (in words, not in code) - right now it;s not clear at all what you need to do, so we are guessing.

Comment: @Riki For example, do you have a navigation property from `Attachment` to `Mappings`?

Answer (score 0):

try `.Contain()` :

```
var attachments = from attm in context.AttachmentToTagMappings
             where tagIds.Contains(attm.TagId)
        select new { attm.FileId};
```

Or you can use `||` instead of `&&` but i think `.Contains()` better less code;)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you need to get a list of **attachments** which its **tagId** exists in an array.

```
var attachments = from attm in context.AttachmentToTagMappings
     where 
         tagIds.Any(id=>id==attm.TagId)
    select new { attm.FileId};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var ids = {1, 2, 3};

var files = context.Files.Where(file => ids.Contains(file.TagId));
if(!ids.AsEnumerable().Except(files.Select(f => f.TagId).AsEnumerable()).Any()){
    return files;
}
return null;
```

Select all files and check that there aren't any ids that don't match to an id in the files and return list of files. If not then return null.

Syntax may not be exact as not tested.