# How can I build linq OR condition base on a list which length is not fixed

Tags: c#, linq

I want to build a OR condition in Linq. And the condition is base on a list.
For example:

```
// list.count == 2
c=>c.state_id==list[0] or c.state_id == list[1];

// list.count == 3
c=>c.state_id==list[0] or c.state_id == list[1] or c.state_id == list[2];
```

For the length of the list is not fixed, so how can I build such condition?
Thanks

Comment: One way is using `Contains`. Check this answer for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34710273/2946329

Answer (score 2):

You can build your query using `Contains` :

```
c => list.Contains(c.state_id);
```

Comment: Impl. note: EF5 (maybe beyond) and L2S bind individual parameters so there is a ~2k-3k list length limit for SQL Server.

Comment: You want to build a SQL `IN` clause and so use LINQ `Contains()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `JOIN`

```
from c in states
join l in list on c.state_id equals l
select c;
```